# Click link in Kickstarter using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to scrape Kickstarter based on the project names alone. Using the project name and the base URL I can get to the search page. In order to scrape the project page, I need to use Selenium to click on the URL. However, I cannot point Selenium to the correct element to click on. I would also like this to be dynamic so I do not need to put the project name each time.

```
<div class="type-18 clamp-5 navy-500 mb3">
    <a href="https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1980119549/knife-block- 
    designed-by-if-and-red-dot-winner-jle? 
    ref=discovery&amp;term=Knife%20block%20- 
    %20Designed%20by%20IF%20and%20Red%20dot%20winner%20JLE%20Design" 
    class="soft-black hover-text-underline">Knife block - 
    Designed by IF and 
    Red dot winner JLE Design
    </a> 
</div>`   

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
url = 'https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?ref=nav_search&term=Knife 
       block - Designed by IF and Red dot winner JLE Design' 
driver.get(url)

elem = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Knife block - Designed by IF and Red 
       dot winner JLE Design')
elem.click()
```

How can I get the elem to point to the correct link?

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Your URL is not correct. You mean this URL: `https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1980119549/knife-block-designed-by-if-and-red-dot-winner-jle`

Comment: You have a typo. *find_elements_by_link_text* should be **element** if you're only expecting one result (since you're trying to click it)

Comment: @JoeT.Boka Don't think that's it. Appears to be a search term and user wants to click the links in the search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your attempt, your code had a typo: using `find_elements....` returns a list of elements so the method `.click()` would not work. You mean to use `find_element`.

To dynamically click links, use an XPath instead. The resulting code would be:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "type-18")]/a')
elem.click()
```

This would grab the first match. You could do `find_elements` and iterate over the elements but this would be a bad approach because since you're clicking the links, each time that renders the previous page stale. If there's more than one, you could use the same XPath but indexed:

```
first_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[contains(@class, "type-18")]/a)[1]')
first_elem.click()
# ...
second_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[contains(@class, "type-18")]/a)[2]')
second_elem.click() 
# And so forth...
```